# How could I get a parameter in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, ognl

Here is my action `execute()` method,

```
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    
    ActionContext aContext = ActionContext.getContext();        
    aContext.getParameters().put("reqVar1", "reqVar1-Value");
    
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to get the parameter value in JSP like below code,

```
<s:property value="#parameters.reqVar1" />
```

but it doesn't work.

I see the parameter is in stack context:

[image]

How could I get the parameter value in JSP?

Comment: Why are you doing this like that? Create property with getter and setter and use it.

Comment: `<s:property value="#parameters.reqVar1" />` should be `<s:property value="%{#parameters.reqVar1}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are always use a type `Map<String, String[]>`. And you need to put parameter correctly, i.e.

```
aContext.getParameters().put("reqVar1", new String[] {"reqVar1-Value"});
```

and get correctly, i.e.

```jsp
<s:property value="%{#parameters.reqVar1[0]}" />
```

The better approach is to use [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) that is included in the `defaultStack` to populate parameters from the request.

**Also see:**

- [How can we access request parameters passed into an Action](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14182#content/view/13977)
- [How to use parameters in JSP](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/jsp.html#request-parameter)