# Changing ParameterAware to HttpParametersAware

Tags: struts2, http-parameters

I'm upgrading my project from Struts 2.3.1 to 2.5.12.
Since `ParametersAware` is deprecated in 2.5.12. I want to change `ParametersAware` to `HttpParametersAware`.

But `setParameter()` method is entirely different in both.

1. `setParameters(HttpParameters parameters)` (struts 2.5.12)
2. `setParameters(Map<String,String[]> parameters)` (Struts 2.3.1)

How to do this?

Comment: Use `HttpParameters`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Map<String,String[]>` to [`HttpParameters`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/HttpParameters.html).  The later class implements a `Map<String,Parameter>`, so you can use 
this to get/put parameters to the map.

The most interesting is a [`Parameter`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/Parameter.html) interface that has implementations
    [Parameter.Empty](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/Parameter.Empty.html), [Parameter.File](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/Parameter.File.html), [Parameter.Request](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/Parameter.Request.html).
The last one is used to retrieve request parameters.

This answer [How could I get a parameter in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876304/573032) will throw a light on a typical usage of *request* parameters if you want to manipulate parameters manually.

Another approach (which is *not* recommended) is to get request parameters from the request itself. See [Interceptors use in login in Struts 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20273764/573032).